# How do I connect a Pioneer AVIC-U250 navigation system to my PC?

Tags: radio

I'm sorry if this is a stupid or simple question but I cannot find the answer after nearly an hour of Googling. For some background I bought a used car with a Pioneer AVH-X7500BT radio in it. It has navigation in it, and as best I can tell, that unit is a Pioneer AVIC-U250. All I want to do is update the maps, but the Naviextras Toolbox says it needs the unit to connect to the PC. The only USB connection I can find in the car is a female end in the glove box that looks like I could stick a flash drive in it. There are videos on Youtube of people updating in this way with Synctool, but my radio doesn't have that.

Does anyone know how this unit is supposed to connect to my PC?

Any help is appreciated. I'm happy to supply more information if it is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.naviextras.com/shop/portal/downloads explains a custom cable is required, and you must use their app . Unable to find the custom cable part number on line; suggest you call 1-800-421-1404 for that information, in case I don't get a useful response to the query I just threw over the transom into their support system by then.

Comment: Both of your links result in the same log-in page for me, so nothing useful is visible.

Comment: @K7AAY I have downloaded and installed the Naviextras Toolbox, but I cannot find any information on the cable. Like fixer1234 said, your links are sending me to a login page that proceeds to the download page for the Toolbox app. Can you provide any more information about this special cable? Thanks!

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for the update. I'll see if I can order the cable.